# Simplify Taylor series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

If we have a Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+2)!} A^k$, how can I simplify this (eg into a simple expression like a sine/cosine)? Note that I do not want to have terms like $A^{-1}$ or $A^{-2}$, i.e. the exponents of $A$ should always be $>=0$.

Comment: Why this remark about the exponents of $A$ ??

Comment: Your sum is over all positive $k$, why do you expect terms in $A^{-k}$?

Comment: Set $A=a^2$, and compare to a cosine.

Comment: Because the inverse of $A$ might not exist; is there any convenient analytic form for this sum?

Comment: @YvesDaoust but then I obtain $\frac{1-\cos{a}}{a^2}$. Apparently, there is no way to avoid this then?

Comment: This can be written $\dfrac12\text{ sinc}^2\left(\dfrac a2\right)$ if you prefer, and the singularity is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:
$$
(1-\cos \left(\sqrt{A}\right))A^{-1}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k A^k}{(2 k+2)!}
$$

To see this, use the fact that:
$$
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k A^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}=\cos(A)
$$
Replace using $A\rightarrow\sqrt{A}$ to get:
$$
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k A^k}{(2 k)!}=\cos(\sqrt{A})
$$
By then changing $2k$ to $2k+2$, you're shifting all coefficients 0,2,4,6,8,...  down one place to get 2,4,6,8,10,... Firstly, this has the effect of removing the $A^0/(0!)=1$ term, so subtract one to get $\cos(\sqrt{A})-1$.

The shift has also caused those coefficients to change sign because of the $(-1)^k$ so now you need to flip the sign of the whole thing to get $1-\cos(\sqrt{A})$

... and finally, because of the shift, those coefficients now appear next to one lower power of $A$ so multiply by $A^{-1}$.